# Page Doesn't Refresh, Validation doesn't works, Page doesn't get redirect but the logic is working

Tags: ajax, laravel

I made simple form which takes only email from a user to subscribe for newsletter using laravel and ajax. When submitting form neither it shows success messages nor error messages.  Also, form validation is not working. This is my controller to handle request

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
          $count = Subscription::where('email', '=' ,$request->email)->count();
          if($count == 1) {
              return redirect()->route('index')   
                          ->with('error','ERROR!! Email Already Subscribed.');
          }
          else
          {
              $request->validate([
                  'email' => 'required',
              ]);
              Subscription::create($request->all());
              return redirect()->route('home')
                      ->with('success','Subscribed !!');
          }     
  }
```

Here, I have checked if the email is already registered or not and this logic is working fine. If email already exists, this won't insert record but it doesn't display error message.

This is my Ajax file written in blade to listen the form request and redirect to controller

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('#subsEmail').on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let email = $('#email').val();

        $.ajax({
          url:"{{ url('/subscription') }}",
          type:"POST",
          data:{
            email:email,
            _token:"{{ csrf_token() }}",
          }
         });
        });
      </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't redirect here, just return an array with a message.

Comment: Thanks. Used `return response()->json([ 'success'=> 'Email aready Exists']);` to display message.